# TempData Unit Testing in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing

How do I port the following class to ASP.NET MVC3? It is part of the [MVC: Unit testing controller actions that use TempData](http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2008/04/13/mvc-unit-testing-controller-actions-that-use-tempdata.aspx) article based on ASP.NET MVC2. The method RenderView() does not exist anymore and has different parameters.

Thanks.

```
// Test-specific subclass for HomeController. This won't be
// needed in the next release of ASP.NET MVC.
private sealed class TestHomeController : HomeController {
    public RouteValueDictionary RedirectValues;
    public string RenderViewName;
    public string RenderMasterName;
    public object RenderViewData;

    protected override void RedirectToAction(RouteValueDictionary values) {
        RedirectValues = values;
    }

    protected override void RenderView(string viewName, string masterName,
        object viewData) {
        RenderViewName = viewName;
        RenderMasterName = masterName;
        RenderViewData = viewData;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you notice that comment at the top.  That seems to indicate this class is not necessary in MVC3, thus no need to port it.

Comment: Yes, but I cannot find any tutorial that explain how to test TempData in ASP.NET MVC3, do you know one?

Comment: Can you show the code for the controller you want to test?

Answer (score 0):

I finally discovered this interesting article on how to test TempData in ASP.NET MVC 3: https://web.archive.org/web/20150419085935/http://www.arrangeactassert.com/how-to-unit-test-asp-net-mvc-controllers/